# Open document from server Android

Tags: android, html, database, document

Sorry for my poor English . I have Some data on server . its book about `2500` pages stored in a single field. i stored it in the same format as `Document` using `CKEditor` . i need to show in my android application in the same `Document` or `Book` format .

I have used `tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(string))` to decode `HTML` tags . it works for some initial text but after that it works but also disturbs the format.

I have two questions.

1. if i use same method to show book... how can i manage format of the text. is that right to get `2500` pages data at the same time..
2. if i stored the whole doc file on the server.. how can i read it in my application without downloading in `sdcard`.  is there any open source library for it or can i open it natively in android?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `Html.fromHtlm()` supports only very basic html 1 standards like `<b> <a>` ...
2. To display real HTML you could use `WebView` which is basically an internet browser embedded in your app
3. You could write a service that will download all your pages in a background thread and store them into a folder on the sd card. Probably an `IntentService` would work. I'm not sure what you want to do, but to load content over http you could use `HttpClient` (part of android sdk) or third party libraries like [okhttp](http://square.github.io/okhttp/)

Comment: i have used Httpclient service.. i don't want to download it because of requirements. can i show doc file from server online.. ?

Comment: Use `WebView` instead of a `TextView`. With `WebView` you can simply load and display any URL with HTML you want to. This can be a web url or a local html file. But `WebView`(depending on Android version) is not fully HTML5 compatible, but should work for the most things including css and javascript.